# Draw image from live arduino sensor data

Tags: arduino, arduino-ultra-sonic

I want to draw real time graph using data coming from a rotating ultrasonic sensor through arduino. What are the tools or library required for this. I am using official arduino IDE using C language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Arduino itself can't really draw a plot, so you'll have to send the data to your computer using Serial communcation. Your computer can then draw a graph. There are two options:

## Use an existing program

The easy way.

[This](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Graph) official Arduino page has some example code for the program [Processing](https://www.processing.org/), but I'm sure you can find a bunch of other examples and tutorials online.

## Write it yourself

This is the difficult and fun way.

If you already know a programming language, great! Search some tutorials about how to connect your Arduino & how to plot data.

Otherwise, I recommend starting with Python, [this](http://www.instructables.com/id/Using-an-Arduino-and-Python-to-plotsave-data/) is a good place to start.

### Java

I have some old code written in Java that connects to the Arduino using the very easy [JSSC](https://github.com/scream3r/java-simple-serial-connector) library:

```
SerialPort port = new SerialPort("COM9");
port.openPort();
port.setParams(9600, 8, 1, 0);

byte b = port.readBytes(1)[0];    //read a single byte
port.writeByte(b);                //write a single byte
```

Where you'd replace "COM9" with whatever port your Arduino is connected to, as displayed in the bottom right of the Arduino IDE.

Actually plotting the data would require another library, I see [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) being recommend a lot online.

Comment: Can you elaborate on write it yourself bcuz this sounds exciting. How do I start

Comment: I know OOP languages like c# or java

Comment: I added some old code and linked a couple of useful libraries, but feel free to ask any other questions you might have! (I hope you meant that you know _how to write_ Java, otherwise this is going to be difficult...)

Comment: thank you. Because of your help i wrote a heart-rate monitoring software in Java here is a link to the video https://www.facebook.com/100009406270471/videos/1706464636343729/

Comment: @DevShekhawat I can't view that page - it says it's protected - but I'm happy I could help! (I'd still love to see the video though) You might want to select the check mark next to my answer to accept it and to indicate your problem was solved.